# jBPM 6 - deploy process definition from API to jbpm-console

Tags: eclipse, api, deployment, process, jbpm

I've created a process definition in jBPM Project in Eclipse and now I'd like to deploy this definition to jbpm-console on remote database.
I found (here:https://developer.jboss.org/thread/234899) two ways to deploy a process, but it's not what I want:

>   - use archetype to create maven project for kjar, then simple mvn clean install and use Deployments view in jbpm console to deploy it
>
>   - push your maven project into jbpm console git repository and build and deploy it from within console - there is GIT integration screen cast on jbpm installer chapter in docs that might be useful

Is there a possibility to do this from API? I mean by using some methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you are looking for some remote API call which allows you to upload your process definitions into the jBPM Console. Am I right?

Unfortunately, there is not such option. The [remote API](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/wb.WorkbenchIntegration.html) only provides methods to manipulate with the resources that are already on the server. And you can get your resources there using one of those two methods you have mentioned.

However, for process definitions there is also a third option which is more user-friendly but there is no easy way how to automate it. You can just create a new business process directly using the web interface of jBPM Console and upload your process definition in jBPM Designer.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't understand my problem well and my question was a bit wrong.  
What if I have my remote database (for example H2)? Is there a possibility to upload a process definition to it (of course by remote API call)?  
And if yes, how to configure a connection with this database?

Comment: When you use the jBPM Console, your process definitions are stored in Git repositories. They are probably also stored in the database during the execution but I do not know exact details about it and I would surely not go the way of manipulating the database records. Anyway, the remote API only allows you to do the same things as the web interface of the jBPM Console.